# maven-metadata.xml not generated in artifactory with jenkins

Tags: xml, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I´m not sure how does POM in maven works correctly. Here is the thing.
I was able to create a job with Jenkins Which  build & publish a WAR from java code, to Artifactory using maven (with artifactory plug in) with job number at the end to keep versioning .Then a maven-metadata.xml is created on artifactory as showed below.

[image]

After that on a second job,  with build with parameters option in jenkins  I choose artifact and deploy the number of war I want like this

[image]

Now I wanted to do the same but using maven to ZIP just a folder and publish to artifactory. I was able  to do that with maven assembly plug in successfully using a POM and a zip.xml file. Thing is that the metadata.xml in artifactory is not generated. It only generates the zip file (also a jar) but not metadata.xml which is needed so I can use jenkins to choose Zip file. here is image from artifactory of Zip generated and error I receive from jenkins:

[image]

[image]

So question is, how does POM generates this metadata.xml file in artifactory? I used same pom of Java project tha was used to build and publish WAR, except that  on   part I included maven assembly plugin to zip file, and zip  was successfully uploaded and created as I showed on image . Here is POM and zip.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.grey</groupId>
    <artifactId>go</artifactId>
    <version>${releaseVersion}</version>

    <name>go</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <releaseVersion>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</releaseVersion>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>  


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

And here is the zip.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>static</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Please need help since I´m dealing with this and is not quite clear. I´m not a developer so my knowledge in java and  pom file and maven is not one of the bests.  thanks for your help!

This is jenkinfile to upload code to artifactory. same as used for Java app.
Only thin changed was repo name in artifactory and the command **"package"** instead of **"clean install"**

```
node {
    def server  = Artifactory.server 'azure-artifactory'
    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
    def buildInfo //= rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install -D releaseVersion="${BUILD_NUMBER}"'

    stage ('Code Checkout') {
                git branch: 'devopstest',
                    credentialsId: '3e3c8889-0dcc-4b4d-bae1-ac140894d292',
                    url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/xxxxxxx'
            }

    stage('Artifactory Configuration') {
        // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
        //rtMaven.tool = 'Apache Maven 3.0.5'
        env.MAVEN_HOME = '/usr/share/maven/'
        // Set Artifactory repositories for dependencies resolution and artifacts deployment.
        rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'go-fe-maven-2'

    }

     stage('Maven build') {
        //buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install -D releaseVersion="${BUILD_NUMBER}"'
        buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'package -D releaseVersion="${BUILD_NUMBER}"'
      //  rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
    }

stage('Publish build info') {
       // server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
       server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }

// Wipe the workspace so we are building completely clean
        deleteDir()
}
```

Comment: Can you update your post to include code of how your are zipping and publishing zip artifacts to Artifactory ?

Comment: I updated code with jenkinsfile

Comment: Is code ok? I don´t know what else could it be

Comment: Solved it. I added "clean" before package command in jenkins file step for building artifact,  and also in POM file I added: <packaging>pom</packaging>